# Windows Phone 7.1 in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I want to upgrade my windows phone app 7.1 to 8.0 in Visual Studio 2015. There is only problem when I want to debug this is the error

```
AppManifest Validation failed. Invalid AppPlatformVersion in WMAppmanifest.xml  PhoneApp2
```

And here is my manifest.cs

```
 <Application 
    x:Class="PhoneApp2.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">

    <!--Application Resources-->
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>

    <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
        <shell:PhoneApplicationService 
            Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing" 
            Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>

</Application>
```

Does some1 know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: That's not your app manifest. That's your App.xaml.

Comment: What should I do with .xaml?

Answer (score 0):

Open WMAppManifest.xml in code view. Try changing the following values - 2012 and 8.0 to the appropriate ones according to your SDK.

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2012/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="8.0">
```

Comment: After doing this:  The element 'Deployment' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2012/deployment' has invalid child element 'App'. List of possible elements expected: 'DefaultLanguage'. PhoneApp2

Comment: Ok, revert the changes. Try this one: Right Click on your Windows Phone project>>Select Properties>>Change the Target Phone OS version under Application Tab

Comment: Ehh I dont really undestand now its    "Project must have either AppxManifest item or Content item with name 'AppxManifest.xml'. PhoneApp2  
"